# how to add scale colour legend to leaflet+openweathermap tile layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openweathermap

is there an easy way, in one line of code, to add default scale colour legend?
[image]

because it is missing
[image]
I use command

```
tempLayer = new L.TileLayer(`https://tile.openweathermap.org/map/temp_new/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?appid=${APIkey_owm}`);
var baseMaps = {
    "osmLayer": osmLayer
};

var overlayMaps = {
    "tempLayer": tempLayer
    
};

L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(mymap);
```

but it does not add scale colour legend automatically..

Comment: What scale's legend are you trying to add? (You don't have any scale data in the map.)

Comment: no, i have temperature data, that's why i post my question. I want to place temperature data scale legend. sorry for my english, its not my native

Comment: Take a look at my example, it is not the same, but you can easily convert it to yourself [svg-markers-width-legends](https://tomik23.github.io/leaflet-examples/#13.svg-markers-width-legends)

Comment: @grzegorz-t thank you, probably i will use your code, thank you again